# Git - creating submodule into specific branch

Tags: git, branch, git-submodules

I want to create submodule only into specific branch, but not for all branchech. Here is an example.

I have two branches: `dev`, and `master`, and I want to have submodules only in `dev` branch, but not in `master`.

Sample file structure
`

```
base-project
|
|-projectA
| |- file.txt
|
|-projectB
| |-file.txt
```

`

I want to have `pojectA` and `projectB` directories as submodule only in `dev` branch, but in `master` branch - as plain directories. Do you know, how to solve it?

Thanks for your all answers.